# Java SQLite : no such column error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a Java app which has to add a record to a database. Everything works fine until I want to add a local variable to the database (I think I'm placing my parentheses wrong or something). Anyway, I'm tired of looking for the problem and would appreciate some help.

My code:

```
public void newUser(int userID, String userName, String credentials) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:c:/temp/alarmsystem.db");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.execute("insert into Users values(" + 1 + "," + userName
                + "," + "'Helloskit'" + ") ");
        core.printToConsole("created");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from Users");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String s = rs.getString("Username");

            core.printToConsole("name = " + s);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

The error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such column: Tombellens
at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:115)
at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:82)
at me.server.DBCommunications.DBConnection.newUser(DBConnection.java:59)
at me.server.Core.Core.newUser(Core.java:61)
at me.server.LocalUser.Console.main(Console.java:72)
```

Thanks, Tom

Comment: **WARNING** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Thomas you have to put username as `'Robert'); DROP TABLE Users; --'` as ' is missing in the query...;)

Comment: Oh, yes. Little Bobby Single Quotes, they call me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is the in query. The `userName` variable is not enclosed in quotes

Use below code:

```
statement.execute("insert into Users values(" + 1 + ",'"  +  userName  + "',"  + "'Helloskit'" +") ");
```

Comment: @Lion why? It looks like a string literal to me.

Comment: I know of someone who's family name is “`O'Sullivan`”. _Single quotes happen in real data._ Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL statement, the variable userName should be in quotes.